# Android Activity Manager REAL_GET_TASKS Error

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Does anyone know how to solve this error message in Android studio:

> 08-10 22:23:05.577     755-1455/? W/ActivityManager﹕
>   getRunningAppProcesses: caller 10099 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS;
>   limiting output

Comment: What are you doing that is triggering this message? In other words, please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: I think this happened after I made notifications

Comment: it is appearing on my logcat as well

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving these logs when testing on Android 5.1.1? This bug was introduced when google deployed a fix to the stagefright bug. *getRunningAppProcesses* requires REAL_GET_TASKS permission in Android M, for some reason 5.1.1 now also requires this permission but requesting it in the manifest does nothing. You won't see this log message but *getRunningAppProcesses* still won't work.